# Creating exe from python program that uses more than one .py file

Tags: python, cx-freeze, setup.py

I have a mid-size program written in Python that i wanted to make avalaible on Windows. I tried using cx_Freeze for that with setup.py looking like this:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\w1kl4s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\w1kl4s\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\\tcl\\tk8.6"


executables = [Executable("main.py", base=None)]

packages = [some, packages]
options = {
    'build_exe': {    
        'packages':packages,
    },    
}

setup(
    name = "ProgramNAme",
    options = options,
    version = "1.0",
    executables = executables
)
```

However, main.py imports other python files from directory, and those files import other ones from directory as well.

Project tree looks something like that

```
├── main.py
└── src
    ├── calculatehash.py
    ├── calculatesizeandhash.py
    └── calculatesize.py
```

And calculatesizeandhash.py imports calculatesize.py and calculatehash.py files.

I don't really want to create more exe files if that's possible(No idea tho)

How should i approach this?

Comment: I do not understand your question. If you use code from `calculatehash.py` in your `main.py` using `import src.calculatehash` or `from src.calculatehash import ...`, you only need to create an executable for `main.py` and `cx_Freeze` usually includes the necessary code automatically.

Comment: If it includes all necessary code, is there a way to debug the exe after that?

Comment: First of all, if you have imported some code from `src.calculatehash.py`, you can check that there is a file `lib/src/calculatehash.pyc` in the build directory (for `cx_Freeze 5.1.1`, or without `lib/ ` for`cx_Freeze` up to version 5.0.1). Then, if you run the exe from a `cmd` console, you should see error messages if any is produced.